# Wordpress 501 Error when post contains number sign

Tags: wordpress, apache

I've a problem with a Wordpress blog.

My post contains some tags like `<span style="color:#ff0000">` to colorize some stuff, obviously. But if I use number sign (#) in that style attribute, when I click to "Update Post", server returns

`HTTP 501 Method Not Implemented  POST to /wp-admin/post.php not supported.`

Then I try to write the name of the color like `<span style="color:red">` there is no error.

Server is Apache & PHP 5.2.6 and `mod_security` is inactive. Also I've tried to put a number sign out of html tags, in text, again there was no problem.

Can you help me?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but try checking your apache error log. Hopefully it will give you valuable info to set you on the right path.

Comment: I'm away from the company which has that project now, so I can't take a look. But If I'm not wrong, I did check out all log files of the apache, php etc.. Thanks anyway...